# How to install javascript libraries in angularjs not being a npm package/bower component

Tags: angularjs, javascript

How do you install javascript libraries where no bower/npm package exists?

Just add the myscript.js to the html?

In the angularjs generated project structure I do not even see a folder for such files because scripts is for my MVC files...

So where and how to add it correctly?

Comment: Please note that there is no *standard* project structure for an angularjs project. If you want a specific answer, you should detail what you have used to generate your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it in an extra sub folder like `scripts/vendor` and add the path to the html.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just include it before your project files.

```
<script src="path/to/your/lib.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="project/controllers.js" type="text/javascript" />
...
```

You also could use something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).